# get a subset of a text file using pandas

Tags: pandas, file

I have a big text file like this example:

example:

```
    CodeClass   Name    Accession   CF33500_02.txt  CF33503_07.txt  CF33505_06.txt
dd  Endogenous  dd  hh  101.238776  8.084376    1.187888
bb  Endogenous  bb  jj  562.853249  2013.886134 1288.568388
gg  Endogenous  gg  ll  218.148969  184.816378  176.705670
kk  Endogenous  kk  tt  23.499524   155.006161  593.654190
```

the 1st row is the header and the 1st column is rows name. I would like to get a subset of this file in which all rows are present but only these columns are in the new file:

```
Name,CF33500_02.txt,CF33503_07.txt,CF33505_06.txt
```

to do so, I am trying to do that using pandas using this code:

```
df = pd.read_table("myfile.txt", index_col=0)
df2 = df.iloc[:, [1, 3, 4, 5]]
```

but it does not work. do you know how to fix it?
it gives this error:

```
: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/John/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1418, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "/home/John/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2092, in _getitem_tuple
    self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
  File "/home/John/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 235, in _has_valid_tuple
    self._validate_key(k, i)
  File "/home/John/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2031, in _validate_key
    raise IndexError("positional indexers are out-of-bounds")
IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

Comment: What is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: @jezrael: >>> print (df.info())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 784 entries, CCNO to ERCC3
Data columns (total 15 columns):
CodeClass                                784 non-null object
Name                                     784 non-null object
Accession                                784 non-null object
CF33500_02.txt    784 non-null float64
CF33503_07.txt    784 non-null float64
CF33505_06.txt    784 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(12), object(3)
memory usage: 98.0+ KB
None

Comment: Just one question. why can't you do something like this to select columns df[['Name','CF33500_02.txt','CF33503_07.txt','CF33505_06.txt']]

Comment: Maybe the best is explain `but it does not work. do you know how to fix it?` - what does mean not working?

Comment: @Ashwini: this a sample file and I am making a script for other analysis in future

Comment: @jezrael: it gives  error

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Comment: @Ashwini: I added to the question.

Comment: Can you please check if your column names are properly aligned. Because when i copy pasted your code, CF.._02.txt & CF.._=/.txt were together in a single column

Comment: The reason you are getting this error because you are trying to retrieve column number 5 which doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `read_table` with your delimiter specified as `\s+`, which will separate columns of values based on if there are one or more white space characters between them.

```
df = pd.read_table("myfile.txt", sep="\s+")

df
    CodeClass   Name  Accession  CF33500_02.txt  CF33503_07.txt CF33505_06.txt
dd  Endogenous  dd      hh       101.238776      8.084376       1.187888
bb  Endogenous  bb      jj       562.853249      2013.886134    1288.568388
gg  Endogenous  gg      ll       218.148969      184.816378     176.705670
kk  Endogenous  kk      tt       23.499524       155.006161     593.654190
```

Then subset the dataframe:

```
cols_to_keep = ["Name", "CF33500_02.txt", 
                "CF33503_07.txt", "CF33505_06.txt"]

df2 = df[cols_to_keep]
df2
    Name    CF33500_02.txt  CF33503_07.txt  CF33505_06.txt
dd  dd      101.238776      8.084376        1.187888
bb  bb      562.853249      2013.886134     1288.568388
gg  gg      218.148969      184.816378      176.705670
kk  kk      23.499524       155.006161      593.654190
```

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: because I think this return future warning

Comment: @jezrael Oh right, didn't realise. No warning for me on `0.23.1`.

Comment: upgrade pandas;) at least 0.24 if not last still a bit buggy

Comment: @jezrael I would if I could! Don't have admin rights to do it at the moment.